# Rooms creation in Node JS for a Multiplayer Games Using Deepstream

Tags: deepstream.io

We are making a game server for casino games over DeepStream, We are writing it in Node JS . I am using DeepStream List to make rooms with a minimum and maximum limit of the clients(List count). A room can only have maximum 5 clients. So if i would say that we have 10000 rooms available and then new user is come to connect then how can i check for free room or DS list which are free for new connection in a fast way basically i need to search that which list have free space or which list's count is less then 5. What is fastest way to do it

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a deepstream database connector, you could write a query that gets not-full rooms from the database and provides them as a deepstream list. With a realtime database like ReThinkDB, change-feeds can be used to update the list in realtime, otherwise you'll need to poll the database with queries.
However, this leaves the issue of users joining a room simultaneously. This could perhaps be handled with valve rules, [see here](https://deepstream.io/tutorials/core/permissions-dynamic/). 
A more traditional approach that avoids that issue would be to use a central [RPC provider](https://deepstream.io/docs/client-js/reqres-response/) to handle requests to join a room, accepting only if there is space available. 
If you aren't using a database, you'll probably want to setup a provider that is responsible for maintaining a list of rooms with spaces, and is also responsible for handling RPC requests to join.